# Grammatically, what is "It" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, subjects, objects

I'm currently working at a private academy in Korea, and my boss just asked me a real head-scratcher.

In the sentence:

> It doesn't have to be hot and humid for players to lose too much water from their bodies.

I'm aware that "It" is a subject pronoun replacing "The weather." Besides that, however, I'm unsure.

Is it a false subject? I wouldn't think so since it's a pronoun. Is it some crazy kind of indirect object?

Anyway, thank you all for your help!

Comment: This is known as the *dummy it*, and the weather is its canonical use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a subject, specifically a ***dummy subject***, realized through the use of a *dummy pronoun*. Talking about the weather is the classic example for dummy subjects in English.

From Wikipedia:

> A **dummy pronoun**, also called an expletive pronoun or pleonastic pronoun, is a pronoun used for syntax without adding further meaning. An example is the "*it*" in "***it is raining***".

And more specifically:

> ***Weather*** it
>
> In the phrase *It is raining*, the verb *to rain* is usually considered semantically impersonal, even though it appears as syntactically intransitive; in this view, the required *it* is to be considered a dummy word.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term "false" subject describes it well. In some languages, we can describe the weather with a single word: "hot." English requires a subject, so we say "It is hot." The "it" doesn't really refer to anything, but it is helpful to think of it as referring to the weather.

Note, I used this idiom above. "It is helpful." *What* is helpful? It! ;)